# Help in identifying a story about a man who controlled wolves by wearing a wolf skin

Tags: story-identification, animals

I remember reading a story about a man who manages to control pack of wolves by wearing the alpha wolf skin as a cloak. It also had a woman or child who would be kept safe in a cave whenever the pack came around by having a boulder rolled into place at the mouth of the cave. Has a dark ending if I remember correctly.
Anyone have any idea of the name of story I am talking about?

Comment: If you take a quick glance at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) I'll bet you can help us out by [edit]ing in a few more details!